# RecyclerView stackFromBottom

Tags: android, listview, stack, android-recyclerview

I just implemented the new `RecyclerView`. I want to use it do display user's messages(sms).

I read on official documentation that `RecyclerView` is a new and improved `ListView` (something like that) and we should use it for better performance.

Everything went great until I wanted to display a user's conversation and I want the messages to be displayed starting from the bottom. In a `ListView` I would normally use `android:stackFromBottom="true"` but when I tried this in the `RecyclerView` it didn't work (even if didn't receive any error).

Does anyone know how to make the `RecyclerView`'s items to be stacked from bottom? Thank you.

Comment: what about `stackFromEnd` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#setStackFromEnd(boolean)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to tyczj's comment I figured it out. In `RecyclerView` instead of `stackFromBottom` you have to use `stackFromEnd` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#setStackFromEnd(boolean)

Answer (score 54):

Making it a little explicit:

```
   final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mActivity);
   layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
   recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```