# FirebaseUI recyclerView how to add to the top?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I using FirebaseUI with RecyclerView.

I need that new value inserted would be at the top of the cards.
In a simple RecyclerView I know that to do this, we adding the new item to position 0 of the arrayList instance everytime.
but with FirebaseUI there is no arrayList, and using by `push` and `setValue` methods we adding the value to the JSON tree.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
private void writeNewPost(String title, String message) {
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();

    String key = myRef.child("reports").push().getKey();
    Report report = new Report(title, message, key);
    Map<String, Object> postValues = report.toMap();

    Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
    childUpdates.put("/reports/" + key, postValues);
    childUpdates.put("/user-reports/" + userID + "/" + key, postValues);

    myRef.updateChildren(childUpdates);  
}
```

Hope you can help, Thank you.

Comment: you can use order by desc query

Comment: @Ganesh: Firebase doesn't offer descending sorts.

Comment: FirebaseRecyclerAdapter will show the data in the order of the underlying location/query. There i no way to reorder it beyond that. But if you're looking to simply reverse the order, there are a couple of ways of doing that. The simplest one I've seen: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/310#issuecomment-247816246

Comment: I'm pretty sure, this would do the trick for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27555686/recycleview-stackfrombottom

Answer (score 0):

When you insert the new item in your database, make sure it has a timestamp. And query for the item and order it with the value of the timestamp.